# How to get the Google Map passing Zone Name?

Tags: google-maps

I want to display the google Map based on zone name. I am getting Zone name in my jsp page  (ie. China Lake, California - USA). I need to pass that and display google Map. How to do that through Google javascript API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried to pass the zonename as location to the geoCoder's function getLocations ?

Let us know if this has worked.

EDIT: Sorry 1 moment hold on. I will post some listing.

```
function userLocSearch(location){
    userInput = location;
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        geocoder = getGeocoder();
        geocoder.getLocations(location,  function(responce){
            if(responce.Status.code==200){
                if(responce.Placemark.length==1){
                    //just one result
                    mapInit(responce.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1],responce.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0],14);
                }else{
                    //more than one result
                    mapInit(responce.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0],responce.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1],14);
                    updateInfoText(responce.Placemark.length);
                }
            }else{
            //error
            //no result
                geocoder.getLocations("USA",  function(responce){
                    mapInit(responce.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[1],responce.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates[0],6);
                });
            }
        });
    }else{
        //TODO 
        //browser not compartible
    }
    return false;
}
```

mapInit is here an other of my functions. The one which initializes the map. 
The one I pasted is just for getting the required geocooredinates by a search string

Comment: Thx for voting me down -.- I have 500 lines classes in Javascript on Google Maps. Too much code to send it all to you. I just thought you were asking how to geocode, not how to init a map. I showed you the geocoder with my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for identifying  Geocode javascript. There was no intention to vote you down. As i didnt resolve my issue by this code, i thought this is not a answer i expected. Then somewhat i did some R&D and found the solution. Anyhow thanks for your initiative.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map = null;
var geocoder = null;

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setUIToDefault();
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    showAddress("Melapalayam,Tirunelveli,Tamilnadu");
  }
}

function showAddress(address) {
  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.getLatLng(
      address,
      function(point) {
        if (!point) {
          alert(address + " not found");
        } else {
          map.setCenter(point, 15);
          var marker = new GMarker(point, {draggable: true});
          map.addOverlay(marker);
          GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
              alert(address);
          });

        }
      }
    );
  }
}
window.onload = initialize;


    </script>
```

- Gnaniyar Zubair